# IntelliJ IDEA groovy console in Java maven project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Is it possible to open up *groovy console* in a *maven* project with classpaths set correctly?

I think that would provide great convenience. As I'm coding Java, I can easily interact with dependent libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through, Grape seems to be the best option.

After opening Groovy Console in IntelliJ, use @Grab annotation to inject dependent library from repository is quite convenient. The only pity is that you have to add an additional library(global or module), Ivy to the Module on which the Groovy console will be open.